# Table nested inside table cell

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-table

I have a table with expandable rows, so each row expands to show another table inside. Sometimes such tables have cell content with long strings; this causes the parent table width to get wider when one of such rows is opened. I would like the parent table to remain the same width and that the child table stick within its 100% `div` container (which is inside a `td`) with `overflow: auto`, so it can be horizontally scrollable.

I made a codesandbox to illustrate better this: https://codesandbox.io/s/tannerlinsleyreact-table-sub-components-94n7n?fontsize=14.

Note that the parent table is inside a `div` with `overflow: auto`, so if you make the window narrower, you will see a horizontal scroll for the parent table. I want this behaviour in the child tables as well, but you'll notice that when expanding a row (by clicking the hand emojis), the parent table gets as wide as the child table.

**EDIT:**
I saw I could just get the parent table's width with JS and fix the width of the container `div` inside the `td`. But I was wondering if this problem has a no-JS solution.

Also, I tried with `table-layout: fixed`, but as explained in my comment, it doesn't solved the issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `table-layout: fixed;` for your outer table.

Comment: I tried that, but data don't fit right when parent table has cells with long strings (which is my case), so I had to put `width: auto`, but for cases in which tables have short data, the table gets shrunk, and I need it to occupy 100% of the space available, so I did `min-width: 100%`, and then I got to the initial point.

Answer (score 0):

**All table width depends on its cell's (TD's) content.**

1) The first way is to give this style table-layout: fixed; to the outer table.

2) The Second Way is, you need to get the outer table width with jquery and assign it to container div (which is inside a TD). And for responsive generates the outer table width on resize of the window and assign it to container div (which is inside a TD). Then the container (which is inside a TD) will be horizontally scrollable.

Comment: 1) I tried that already, as explained in my comment to my question.
2) I saw I could get what I wanted by fixing the width of the container width, which implies getting the parent table's width with JS, but I wanted to know if there was a no-JS solution for this problem.

Comment: Thanks, @dalvallana for your revert but for the no- JS solution, there is only one option which you have to give this style "table-layout: fixed;" to the outer table.